# How can I access a VM instance using https in GCP

Tags: https, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have created a VM and installed tomcat server in GCP and enabled http and https access. But while using https along with external IP I am unable to access. It works while using http.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of the **HTTPS** secure web access can be implemented in two main ways when working with CGE instances:

- Set up an instance to terminate HTTPS
- Configure a HTTPS load balancer

I recommend you to take a look on the [HTTPS and SSL](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely#https-and-ssl) and [Creating and Using SSL Certificates](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates) official Google documentation that contains detailed information about the steps required to create this configuration as well as some security method alternatives.

Comment: What is CGE again?

Comment: I believe they meant GCE (Google Compute Engine)